# Jest ReferenceError: Cannot access before initialization

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

My Service.ts

```
import { getDecider } From './decider';

const decider = getDecider();
const Service = {
    getUrl(): string {
        return decider.exp.isB('exp1') ? 'b-url' : 'a-url';
    }
};
```

My Service.test.ts

```
const isBMock = jest.fn();
const deciderMock = {
    exp: {
        isB: isBMock,
    },
    blah: 'test',
};

const getDeciderMock = jest.fn();
jest.mock('./decider', () => ({
    getDecider: getDeciderMock,
});

import { Service } from './Service';

describe('test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        isBMock.mockReturnValue(true);
        getDeciderMock.mockReturnValue(deciderMock);
    });

    it('should return b-url', () => {
        const result = Service.getUrl();
        expect(result).toBe('b-url');
    });
});
```

If I run the test I get the following error.

**ReferenceError: Cannot access 'getDeciderMock' before initialization**

I read a lot on how jest does hosting but none of it helped.

Any one faced similar issue and knows the solution for this?

I'm using TypeScript, jest, swc for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the `getDeciderMock` to `mockGetDecider`.
And remember to use the `mock` prefix for your mock functions.

Please read the [`caution` section and the first sentence after it](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no problem with your usage of getDeciderMock.

I faced with the same issue only when I changed the order of mocking and importing.

If we import the variable x from some module, it throws an error only if I mocked it after the imports

```
// This one throws an error
import { getDecider } From './decider';
const getDeciderMock = jest.fn();
  jest.mock('./decider', () => ({
  getDecider: getDeciderMock,
});


// While this one works fine
const getDeciderMock = jest.fn();
  jest.mock('./decider', () => ({
  getDecider: getDeciderMock,
});
import { getDecider } From './decider';
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case the issue was the naming of the element .

```
const TextareaLabel = getByTestId("textarea-label");
```

So I fixed the issue with using camel case naming :

```
const textareaLabel = getByTestId("textarea-label");
```